# How Can I execute all JavaScript on a page before using Selenium (Python)?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage and I am attempting to find particular elements within it using Selenium with Python.

The issue I'm having is that all of the elements I am trying to find are all dynamically generated using JavaScript. I have printed out the entirety of the page source that my Selenium script is being fed, and it would appear that it is purely what the server has sent my browser - pure HTML with JavaScript scripts that need to run to create the page as I see it in a browser.

i.e. The code I am requiring to inspect using Selenium is the code that I can see when inspecting elements using the Chome Developer Tools (when all scripts have been run), and instead it is receiving the straight HTML just as you would see when right clicking on the page and choosing "View page source".

I am currently using Edge and the Edge WebDriver as there is no webdriver for Chrome version 122 (only 123...) and Chrome version 123 has not been released yet.

Do you know of a way to ensure Selenium is being passed the completed webpage with all JS scripts having been run?

In the mean time I shall attempt to write a piece of code that gathers all the script elements and runs them one by one to see if that works, but intuitively I feel there's a better way to do it!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use explicit webdriverwaits with expected conditions: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-waits  These are designed to deal with dynamically generated content.  (If you don't use the waits, your code will run before the DOM has been updated.)

Answer (score 0):

I added an explicit wait to solve the issue. To do this, I found what loaded last for every page, which turned out to be a search box, and added waited for the search box. The code below is an example of the explicit wait for the search box. Make sure to replace 'search box name' with the name of your search box.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "[search box name]")))
```